# "Extension Install Failure: Package is invalid. Details: 'Invalid value for 'page_action.default_icon'.'"

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, manifest

I've written Chrome extensions before but this is my first time using manifest version 2. So, I thought I should research first-hand how far back v2 is supported so that I can apply a `minimum_chrome_version`.

However, for some reason, whenever I try to install my extension on any version of Chrome < v23 (the current, I believe), I'm getting an error of `Package is invalid. Details: 'Invalid value for 'page_action.default_icon'.'.` (see screenshots) when trying install the extension from the original source, the packed `CRX`, or the unpacked `CRX`.

The strange thing is, I'm not even using `page_action` - I'm using `browser_action`...

I'm getting this error on Chrome versions:

- 10.0.648.133
- 15.0.874.106
- 18.0.1025.168
- 19.0.1084.56
- 20.0.1132.47
- 21.0.1180.77
- 22.0.1229.0

and probably everything other version.

Anyway, here's my `manifest.json` :

```
{
    /* Appearance */
    "name": "Save as Shortcut",
    "description": "Save the current page's URL as a shortcut file (*.url)",
    "icons": {  "16": "images/icons/icon_16.png",
                "48": "images/icons/icon_48.png",
                "128": "images/icons/icon_128.png" 
             },

    /* Linked code */
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": {
            "19": "images/icons/icon_19.png",
            "38": "images/icons/icon_38.png"
        },
        "default_title": "Save this page's URL as a shortcut file (*.url)",
        "default_popup": "html/popup.html"
    },

    /* Technical details */
    "version": "0.10.200",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    /* "minimum_chrome_version": "23.0.0.0", */

    /* Security */
    "permissions": [
        "tabs"
    ]
}
```

[image: Installing]

[image: Error message]

(Screenshots taken of Chrome v20.0.1132.43)

Edit 1: ...Anyone?

Edit 2: Cmannn. Don't let me tumbleweed. ;/

Edit 3: *tumbleweeds*

Edit 4: Seriously? No one knows? That's a first..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though the syntax was, to the best of my eyesight, identical to [Google's own example](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html#manifest) (apart from the path and filename), the lines that caused the error were:

```
"default_icon": {
    "19": "images/icons/icon_19.png",
    "38": "images/icons/icon_38.png"
},
```

Using the following block, instead of the previous one, fixed the error (in Chrome v20, at least):

```
"default_icon": "images/icons/icon_38.png"
```

[As stated in Google's documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html#manifest), Chrome will auto-resize the larger icon to fit smaller requirements, so there shouldn't be any functional or aesthetic loss.

As the first codeblock works seamlessly in Chrome v23, I can only assume that the issue was caused by a glitch in Google's implementation of the version 2 manifest that was present in v < 23 but was fixed in v23.

Although, I haven't heard of many issues, so I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me, i got rid of problem only after commenting out "minimum_chrome_version"

Comment: I'm pretty sure it happened before I even added the `minimum_chrome_version` line, but I'll try completely removing it now.

Comment: try "minimum_chrome_version": "23.0" instead

Comment: Yep. Same problem without any comments and the entire `minimum_chrome_version` line.

Answer (score 0):

For me, Icons was by default set to an array and I changed it to object with my icon.

"icons": { "32": "icons/eye_icon-32.png" }

It then fixed the error